# Clickhouse - sum of array filtered by different array

Tags: sql, arrays, clickhouse

I have a table of arrays that holds information about customers sessions. I need to make a query, that will show me summary of PurchaseAmount by each CustomerID.
My table looks like this one:

```
SELECT 
    [325, 516, 343, 539] as CustomerID,
    arrayEnumerate(CustomerID) as CustomerIndex,
    [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,3,4,1,1,2,3] as PurchaseIndex,
    [200, 100, 200, 200, 0, 500, 100, 900, 100, 200, 0, 150, 350] as PurchaseAmount
```

[Existing table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxFRS.png)

I've tried to use arrayMap, but CustomerIndex and PurchaseIndex are different length, so that ends up with an error. arraySum shows me summary for whole PurchaseAmount array. sumMap seems a bit off
Wanted results looks like this: [Wanted result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFbMV.png)
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's a mistake to store data like this: `PurchaseIndex`.

PurchaseIndex takes excessive space, CustomerID will be compressed to the same PurchaseIndex. Basically you have doubled the stored data.

You should store it as

```
[325, 516, 343, 539, 325, 516, 343, 343, 539, 325, 325, 516, 343] AS CustomerID,
[200, 100, 200, 200,   0, 500, 100, 900, 100, 200,   0, 150, 350] AS PurchaseAmount
```

I guess you have provided half-baked result, if yes, then provide `createtable/insert` of your real data layout.

```sql
SELECT sumMap(arrayMap(i -> (CustomerID[i]), PurchaseIndex), PurchaseAmount) AS res
FROM
(
    SELECT
        [325, 516, 343, 539] AS CustomerID,
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 3] AS PurchaseIndex,
        [200, 100, 200, 200, 0, 500, 100, 900, 100, 200, 0, 150, 350] AS PurchaseAmount
)
┌─res────────────────────────────────────┐
│ ([325,343,516,539],[400,1550,750,300]) │
└────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

---

```sql
SELECT
    CustomerID,
    PurchaseAmount
FROM
(
    SELECT sumMap(arrayMap(i -> (CustomerID[i]), PurchaseIndex), PurchaseAmount) AS res
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            [325, 516, 343, 539] AS CustomerID,
            [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 3] AS PurchaseIndex,
            [200, 100, 200, 200, 0, 500, 100, 900, 100, 200, 0, 150, 350] AS PurchaseAmount
    )
)
ARRAY JOIN
    res.1 AS CustomerID,
    res.2 AS PurchaseAmount

┌─CustomerID─┬─PurchaseAmount─┐
│        325 │            400 │
│        343 │           1550 │
│        516 │            750 │
│        539 │            300 │
└────────────┴────────────────┘
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That helped. 
Basically, arrayMap(i -> (CustomerID[i]), PurchaseIndex was the key for my task.